# How do I use the 'about' Schema.org property?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I'm trying to markup an article and confused as to how to use the `about` property (from CreativeWork).

http://schema.org/about

My guess is that it can be used like this...

```
<p itemprop="about">Short text about the article...</p>
```

But on schema.org it says that the expected type is `Thing` so I'm not sure what I should be inserting inside the `itemprop="about"` tag; I can't find any examples of the `about` property in use.

Can anyone help and provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Microdata, the syntax would look like:

```html
<p itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
  …
</p>
```

(Instead of `Thing`, you could use a more specific type.)

Now you can use properties for this Thing, for example giving it a [`name`](http://schema.org/name), [`sameAs`](http://schema.org/sameAs) to link to the corresponding Wikipedia page, and [`description`](http://schema.org/description) for a short description:

```html
<p itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
  <span itemprop="description">A <span itemprop="name">Bee</span> is a flying insect.</span>
  <link itemprop="sameAs" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bee" />
</p>
```